# Vsplit in resized GUI Window in .vimrc

Tags: gvim, split

When I'm in the GUI, I like to have a large-ish vim window: 161 columns, so I can `:vsplit` it into two 80 column windows (with 1 extra column for the gutter.) This works perfectly fine if I do it by hand, but if I try to `:vsplit` in my `.vimrc`, I get a 40 column window and a 120 column window.

The appropriate part of my `.vimrc` is here:

```
if has("gui_running")
    " GUI is running or is about to start.
    set lines=51 columns=161
    set guioptions -=T
    set guifont=InputMono:h10
    " Split the window
    set equalalways
    vsplit
endif
```

Can anyone say what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that `set columns=161` does not take effect immediately.  Maybe not until Vim displays a window, which according to `:h startup` happens after the vimrc is read.  The latter is processed in the third step of the documentation, while the windows are still not displayed in the 11th step:

> 11. Open all windows
>           When the |-o| flag was given, windows will be opened (**but not displayed yet**).
>           When the |-p| flag was given, tab pages will be created (**but not displayed yet**).

In any case, try to delay `:vsplit` until `VimEnter` (12th and last step in the initialization process), so that you're sure that all the initializations have been performed, and a Vim window with the correct geometry is currently displayed:

```
au VimEnter * vsplit
```

Which gives:

```
if has('gui_running') && has('vim_starting')
    " GUI is running or is about to start.
    set lines=51 columns=161
    set guioptions -=T
    set guifont=InputMono:h10
    " Split the window
    set equalalways
    au VimEnter * vsplit
endif
```

Comment: Putting autocommands in groups is usually better, though I guess you don’t really need it here

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what causes this, but I would try the following workarounds if it's important to you to setup the splits on startup (it usually isn't for me—I either have a session with saved layouts, or I don't):

1. Try `wincmd =` to equalize the windows after `vsplit`ting them; or,
2. Try `execute (&columns / 2) "vsplit"` to split in half

---

P.S. Usually, it's best to keep gui-related configuration in `~/.gvimrc` or `~/.vim/gvimrc`.

Comment: My .vimrc is in need of a bit of cleanup and refactoring, for sure.